# How do I synchronize Unity Object actions with music for a HoloLens show?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, event-handling, hololens

I'm making a HoloLens version of the Epcot fireworks show, IllumiNations. What's the best way to trigger events like explosion animations, items appearing/disappearing, and making certain GameObjects increase or decrease in scale. I'm hoping there's a way to do it that doesn't involve coding each object to listen to the music for the right time as that would be very time consuming. I've seen a program similar to what I need called Koreography but I am broke so I cant afford an $85 program. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to do it without needing to code to listen to music is manually. You listen to the music, and make time markers along the music track with different indicators for each type of firework that you would want to explode at that moment. Then simply spawn each firework a few moments before should explode, and it include the complete animation + explosion noises, and destroy itself.

Comment: Wow, literal days of googling things like "sync events with music" and that one key phrase "time markers"  brought me to the official unity tutorial for doing exactly what i need to do I just didn't know the correct term. thank you so much!